# How to execute 2 While loops containing the same condition in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, opencsv

I am using the Java OpenCSV library to read and write a new file. The requirement is to write a `@` symbol at the end of each line except the last one.
I am succeeded with adding `@` after each line but the last line must not contain `@`. A part of my Java program is as follows:

```
// A part of my Java code
String[] endOfLine;
String[] nextLine;
int endLine = 0;
int lineNumber = 0;

// To get how many line are in the input file
while ((endOfLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    endLine++;
}

//For 8 lines endLine is 8 here - which is ok
//Now I want to pass this in next while loop - which is also ok

while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    lineNumber++;
    channel_temp = nextLine[5];

    if (lineNumber == endLine) {

        //Build a new string with all our required data
        String newdata = channel_temp;
        writer.writeNext(newdata);
        System.out.println(newdata);
    }

    else {

         String newdata2 = channel_temp + "@";
         writer.writeNext(newdata2);
         System.out.println(newdata2);
    }
}

System.out.println("lineNumber: " + lineNumber);
System.out.println("endLine: " + endLine);
```

The program shows the output as:

```
lineNumber: 0
endLine: 8
```

So, why is my `while loop` not updating **lineNumber** value? 
In which part I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise `reader` again. After the first loop, it is at the end of the file. Therefore, in the second loop, reader.readNext() returns null and so it never enters the second loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood the problem. Reopening the file would not be a good idea but how do I reinitialize reader before the second while loop?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to reinitialize the reader without reopening the file. I you do not want to reopen the file the most efficent and probably best way would be to merge to two loops.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me if I create another instance of _reader_ and then call it in 2nd while loop. At the begining I was trying to do it in one while loop but I couldn't find the right way to do it. Can anyone have some better idea to do it?

Comment: If I were to do it in one while loop I would probably have the while loop be one step behind and process the last line outside the while loop. But maybe someone else has an even better way to do it.

Comment: Another instance of reader is the same as opening the file again. You could use a do-while loop instead to merge the two loops. nextLine = reader.readNext() will be inside the loop. Your condition would be nextLine!=null.

Comment: No, It doesn't serve my purpose. do-while loop also does the same like while loop only if I create a new instance of my _reader_ . So, till now the only solution is to create a new instance of _reader_ in between two while loops. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your aim is.

Answer (score 0):

In your first while loop you are reading the whole file. In you second while loop you try to use the same reader to read the same file again, except this reader is already at the end of the file so your the nextLine() call will return null. So my bet is that the second while loop does not execute.

To solve this you could either do everything in one while loop or re-open the file for the second loop.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the same reader to perform second while loop.

Consider initialize reader again. Then second while loop will start from the beginning.